# RoR - Change Swagger API path to api.my-domain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, url, swagger

I have [swagger-ui_rails](https://github.com/d4be4st/swagger-ui_rails) integrated in my existing Rails app. It successfully browses api-docs at http://my-domain.com/api-docs and my API is hosted on http://my-domain.com/api/v1/my-model.json.

**How can I change my API path to http://api.my-domain.com/v1/my-model.json ?**

**Do I need to create a sub domain api.my-domain.com as well ?**

My `swagger_docs.rb` looks like this:

```
class Swagger::Docs::Config
  def self.transform_path(path)
    "api-docs/#{path}"
  end
end

Swagger::Docs::Config.register_apis({
  "1.0" => {
    :api_extension_type => :json,
    :api_file_path => "public/api-docs",
    :base_path => "http://www.my-domain.com/",
    :clean_directory => true
  }
})
```

After running `rake swagger:docs`, my `api-docs.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://www.my-domain.com/",
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "api-docs/api/v1/my-model.{format}",
      "description": "My Models"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I browse http://www.my-domain.com/api/v1/my-models, it renders data correctly, looks like following:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "www_path_prefix": "http://www.my-domain.com/",
    "api_path_prefix": "http://www.my-domain.com/api",
    "version": 1
  },
  "data": {
    "paging": {
      "next_page_url": "http://www.my-domain.com/api/v1/my-models?page=2",
      "total_items": 2438,
      "number_of_pages": 49,
      "items_per_page": 50,
      "current_page": 1
    },
    ....
```

**Note**: I am not using `grape-swagger`.

Comment: I am using swagger-ui_rails to show api-docs, and hand-coding controllers for API.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for here.

Comment: I want my API endpoints to look like: http://api.my-domain.com/v1/my-model.json instead of http://www.my-domain.com/api/v1/my-model.json.

Comment: Aha! You want to use a different subdomain for the docs. I'd clearly state that in the question ;) Not sure if you can do it with swagger-docs directly, but you can probably employ a proxy to reroute the requests of those pages.

Comment: To clarify, at first place I want to use a subdomain 'api.my-domain.com' for API calls (not api-docs!)

Comment: Then that seems like it has nothing to do with Swagger :)

Comment: @webron I am not sure about why its nothing to do with Swagger ? If i have a subdomain (api.my-domain.com) setup, it loads the RoR application always and my API calls are still going to my-domain.com/api/v1/.... What should I do in Swagger to force API to be at api.my-domain.com/v1/... ?

Comment: If everything is already deployed on the subdomain, you only need to change the basePath to be the subdomain as well. In your pasted code, it's `base_path`.

Comment: I have changed `base_path` to `api.my-domain.com`. Now my API endpoints looks like `http://api.my-domain.com/api/v1/my-models`. This might be due to `www_path_prefix` and `api_path_prefix` settings under `metadata` above. So finally is there a way to change these settings so that my API endpoint would look nicer like: `http://api.my-domain.com/v1/my-models` ?

Comment: You want to change the API endpoints or the documentation endpoints? Swagger is just a documentation tool, it doesn't affect your API.

Comment: I apologies for the confusion, I am new to RoR world though. I want to change my API end points at first place.

Comment: No worries. I have no experience with RoR at all. It *is* possible that the swagger-docs library also exposes the API and not just document it, but I wouldn't know. Just clarifying that this is not directly related to Swagger as a documentation specification. I hope someone else could provide the answer there.